# Getting multiple images from AJAX but Each is displaying after the image extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am passing multiple ids to fetch the image name but each image is displaying after the name of the image. please check below output.

```
<img src="images/profile/1496108249.jpgavatar.pngavatar.png" alt="">
```

I need output like this.

```
<img src="images/profile/1496108249.jp" alt="">
<img src="images/profile/avatar.png" alt="">
<img src="images/profile/avatar.png" alt="">
```

What I am trying to achieve. I am creating add to compare section. I have more than 100 users with a check box. If any user selects the check box one by one then it will call the AJAX with an id of the selected user and display the image of the user.

Example: I have selected user id 5 it will call the AJAX and display the image of the user. At the same time If I select user id 10 then it will call the AJAX and display the image name of user 5 as well as 10. Same as If I select use id 100 and Pass to AJAX and display the image name. but it will display the Image 5, 10, 100.

So I just want to know what logic should I use it?

**compare_process.php**

This will display the image name of selected users

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['users'];
$sql_compare='SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $compare_pic=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
        echo $compare_pic;
    }
}

exit();
```

**Ajax**

It will get the selected id and pass to PHP

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  arr = [];
  $("[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    arr.push($(this).val());
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/compare_process.php",
      data: 'users=' + arr,
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#pics_name").html("<img src='images/profile/" + msg + "' alt='' />");
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("failure");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input class="check-hidden" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $compare_u;?>" name="compare_peer" id="compare_peer" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return a JSON array from PHP:

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['users'];
$sql_compare='SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
$compare_pic = array();
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $compare_pic[]=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($compare_pic);    
exit();
```

then loop through the array in Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  arr = [];
  $("[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    } else { // Remove value if unchecked
        var index = arr.indexOf($(this).val());
        if (index != -1) {
            arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "includes/compare_process.php",
      data: { users: arr },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {
        $("#pics_name").empty();
        $.each(msg, function() {
          $("#pics_name").append("<img src='images/profile/" + this + "' alt='' />");
        });
      },
      error: function() {
        alert("failure");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Absolutely correct Mr.Barmar. I just need one more help in this. Can you share some knowledge about if I unchecked the checkbox then selected image auto-hide? like If I unchecked Id 5 then Image related to it will hide. Is it possible?

Comment: Use `if(this.checked)` to see if it's checked. If it's not checked, remove the value from the array instead of adding it.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mr.Barmar sir, I was struggling this issue from last 5 days and you solved it within 5 min. Great sir. Thank you, sir. Upvote from my site

Comment: Incase I have to display the Id of all images than How can I display it?

Comment: @Hybreeder You could return an 2-dimensional array with `id` and `profile_pic`. Then the Javascript can use `this.id` and `this.profile_pic` to put them in the appropriate places.

Comment: Yes, it needs to create a multi-dimensional array and then encode it as JSON.

Comment: Is this write code? $compare_pic[]=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
    $compare_Id[]=$userdata12['Id'];
    $myArray = [
           'compare_pic' => $compare_pic,
           'compare_Id'  => $compare_Id
      ];echo json_encode($myArray);

Comment: I would do it the other way around. `$myArray[] = array('profile_pic' => $userdata12['profile_pic'], 'id' => $userdata12['id']);`

Comment: That way you keep all the related data together.

Comment: You can also change the SQL to `SELECT profile_pic, id`, and then just use `$myArray[] = $userdata12;`

Comment: But know When I clicked on check box it is displaying the image and id but it is displaying twice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153010/discussion-between-hybreeder-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

1. You could loop over what checkboxes are checked with `$('input[type=checkbox]:checked')` Loop over those, and send that to the PHP script.
2. You could do it per checkbox, and 'append' it with JS to some element. So instead of the `.html(<img>)` `.append(<img>)` in the success statement of the ajax call.