# How to display multiple values from AJAX in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have to display multiple values from AJAX but I am getting only single value.

**Concept:**
The user will select single or multiple check box and according to the checkbox, it will display the image and user_id. I am able to display the image but not able to display the user_id. Would you help me in this?

I just upload only AJAX and PHP code

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/compare_process.php", // 
    data:'users='+arr,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
        $("#pics_name").empty();
        $.each(msg, function() {
            $("#pics_name").append("<img src='images/profile/" + this + "' alt='' />");
            $("#pics_Id").append();//I have to display id here
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['users'];
$sql_compare='SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
    while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
        $compare_pic[]=$userdata12['profile_pic'];
        $compare_Id=$userdata12['Id'];
    }
}
echo json_encode($compare_pic, $compare_Id);
exit();
```

Comment: [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) takes one Array as input, you are passing two. Save all your output to return in one Array and then json_encode it.

Comment: And how can I display in AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not putting `$compare_Id` into an array. You need to create a 2-dimensional array in the PHP.

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['users'];
$sql_compare='SELECT id, profile_pic FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
$compare_pic = array();
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
     while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $compare_pic[]=$userdata12;
     }
   }
echo json_encode($compare_pic);
exit();
```

Then access each property in the Javascript.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/compare_process.php", // 
    data:'users='+arr,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
        $("#pics_name,#pics_Id").empty();
        $.each(msg, function() {
            $("#pics_name").append("<img src='images/profile/" + this.profile_pic + "' alt='' />");
            $("#pics_Id").append("<div>" + this.id + "</div>");
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's correct.It's working. In case If I need any other field that I have to add the field name in SQL query and this.fieldname can retrieve the value. Right?

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for helping me again, I am a big fan of you. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 1):

the second argument in function `jsonencode` is for options according following link:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

for passing multiple values you can put your variables into an array then put this array in function `jsonencode`

so you can do something like this in your php code:

```
$myArray = [
     'compare_pic' => $compare_pic,
     'compare_Id'  => $compare_Id
];

echo json_encode($myArray);
```

then you get each value in your response in jQuery code like this:

```
 var firstValue  = msg.compare_pic
 var secondValue = msg.compare_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "includes/compare_process.php", // 
    data:'users='+arr,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(msg){
        $("#pics_name").empty();
        $.each(msg, function (index, value) {
            $("#pics_name").html("<img src='images/profile/" + value.profile_pic + "' alt='' />");
            $("#pics_Id").html(value.Id);
        });
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("failure");
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$_SESSION['compare_user']=$_POST['users'];
$sql_compare='SELECT * FROM request WHERE Id IN (' .( is_array( $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) ? implode( ',', $_SESSION['compare_user'] ) : $_SESSION['compare_user'] ).')';
$compare_pic = array();
$compare_query=$conn->query($sql_compare);
if ($compare_query->num_rows > 0) {
     while($userdata12=$compare_query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $compare_pic[]=$userdata12;
     }
   }
echo json_encode($compare_pic);
exit();
```

This should get you started. The above code is returning single array as JSON. In JavaScript, you can display any required property where needed.

Comment: Mr.Bilal, I am getting Id but If I click the first check box then getting the first id if I clicked on second check box then I am getting second Id as well as First id

Comment: Because you used append in your code. I have update the code above. Check now.

Comment: Or you can just write the changes from the OP code and post some additional explanations

Comment: Yes I used append because I have to display all the Id which user selected but not duplicate.

Comment: Mr.@user10089632 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877726/getting-multiple-images-from-ajax-but-each-is-displaying-after-the-image-extensi/45877890?noredirect=1#comment78714621_45877890

Comment: Please check above link. 2 days before I ask a question.Hope you will get idea

Comment: This answer is overwriting `#pics_Id` every time through the loop, so it only has the last ID.